# eb deploy --staged usage

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Back in EB version 2 , when using the git aws.push command, if a push had been done recently, then the next push would not take long at all, I assumed it was only pushing up the changed files, rather than the whole repo.

In Eb version 3, the EB Deploy command appears to upload everything every time.

The Docs say that there is a --staged option

```
Deploy files staged in the git index instead of the HEAD commit.
```

Is this equivalent to the old way where it would only upload the changed files? or am I misunderstanding how this command should be used.

usually uploading the whole thing is ok, but when a quick fix needs to be made, having a faster way to upload was useful. So I am just after some clarification if the --staged command will do what I think it does, and only upload the changed files from the last push?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `--staged` is tightly coupled with git and simply means to deploy files from the local git repository, where those files where not yet committed, but rather staged.
If you're unfamiliar with the `git stage` command, it basically means that you mark files to be committed in the next `git commit` command you'll issue. More in the [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics).
So as for your question - the `--staged` flag will still upload the repository, and won't be faster.
This feature is used mainly for testing purposes, where you want to test new code without committing it.